# Interaction undefined discord.js slash commands

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Good evening, I am attempting to migrate my text-based commands to slash commands. I have run in to a problem when trying to get a slash command option, getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')`. Now I know the interaction variable is being passed because my ping slash command manages to reply fine.

Here is the code for the command:

```js
execute(interaction) { // inside here command stuff
        if (interaction.options.getString('type') === 'add') {
            const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('././config.json'));
            if (data.blocked.includes(interaction.options.getMentionable('user').id())) return (interaction.reply('That person is already blocked.'));
            data.blocked.push(interaction.options.getMentionable('user').id);
            fs.writeFileSync('././config.json', JSON.stringify(data));
            interaction.reply(`Successfully blocked ${interaction.options.getMentionable('user').tag}.`);
        }
    },
```

And the command configuration:

```js
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('block')
        .setDescription('Blocks or unblocks a user from using the bot.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('type')
                .setDescription('Whether to block or unblock the user.')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoice('add', 'add')
                .addChoice('remove', 'add'))
        .addMentionableOption(option =>
            option.setName('user')
                .setDescription('The user to block or unblock.')),
```

And the interactionCreate event:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error executing ${command.name}:\n${error}`);
        await interaction.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!', true);
    }
});
```

Am I trying to get an option incorrectly? Does the `getMentionable()` not return a user object? What can I do to fix this error? Maybe someone less sleep-deprived can help. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: please indicate if the answer below fixed your issue or not

Answer (score 0):

Try these out.

```js
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('block')
    .setDescription('Blocks or unblocks a user from using the bot.')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option
        .setName('type')
        .setDescription('Whether to block or unblock the user.')
        .setRequired(true)
        .addChoice('add', 'add')
        .addChoice('remove', 'remove'))
    .addUserOption(option => // addUserOption rather than addMentionableOption
        option
        .setName('user')
        .setDescription('The user to block or unblock.')),
```

```js
//changed all getMentionable to getUser
async execute (interaction) { // inside here command stuff
    if (interaction.options.getString('type') === 'add') {
        const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('././config.json'));
        if (data.blocked.includes(interaction.options.getUser('user').id)) {
            return interaction.reply('That person is already blocked.')
        } else {        
            data.blocked.push(interaction.options.getUser('user').id);
            fs.writeFileSync('././config.json', JSON.stringify(data));
        interaction.reply(`Successfully blocked ${interaction.options.getUser('user').tag}.`);
        }
    }
}
```

`MENTIONABLE` sets the option to require a user, role or snowflake as value

`USER` sets the option to require a user or snowflake as value